# Suggestion on statistical models that compare likeness

Tags: anova, statsmodels

I have a large dataset with thousands of entries. there are two columns the first being a type value (A,B,C,D,E,F) and the second column is a raw data value.  I'd like to run statistical analysis on this dataset in order to determine which of the type are similar to each other based on the values in in the second column.  ANOVA test is the first test that comes to mind, as the allows me reject a null hypothesis (ie, A=B=C=D=E=F) based on a P-Value.  Are the other tests that I can do that confirm or reject that they are similar? Sorry I am new to statistical models.